# Can we use Asp.Net Membership and Role Provider in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, membership-provider

I'm converting a MVC 3 application to MVC 5. I've been reading on web that MVC 5 comes with Asp.Net Identity for security. My question is that is possible, feasible and good to use old membership and role provider in MVC 5 application. 
Can anyone give any useful link where I can learn conversion from membership and role provider to Identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to migrate Membership provider to Identity if you don't want to. MVC5 will happily work with Membership provider. I have migrated MVC3 with Membership provider to MVC5 and had no problems with users.

Recently I have migrated from Membership to Identity and also had no major problem migrating - just followed the instructions in the link already provided.

Comment: can you provide me link for mvc5 using membership provider? @trailmax we have a custom membership structure

Comment: @CyberNinja MVC5 is almost the same as MVC3 in this respect. Find any MVC3 Membership tutorial and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/ contains samples to convert apps from older memberships to Identity. These might be helpful. Also look at http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations for more information on migrating apps